# Spark Java encoders - switch fields on collectAsList

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following schema in a dataset -

```
root
 |-- userId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- data: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- startTime: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- endTime: long (nullable = true)
 |-- offset: long (nullable = true)
```

And I have the following classes (+ setter and getters which I omitted for simplicity) -

```
public class MyClass {

    private String userId;

    private Map<String, MyDTO> data;

    private Long offset;
 }

public class MyDTO {

    private long startTime;
    private long endTime;

}
```

I collect the result the following way -

```
    Encoder<MyClass> myClassEncoder = Encoders.bean(MyClass.class);
    Dataset<MyClass> results = raw_df.as(myClassEncoder);
    List<MyClass> lst = results.collectAsList();
```

I do several calculations to get the result I want and the result is correct all through the way before I collect it.
This is the result for -

```
results.select(results.col("data").getField("2017-07-01").getField("startTime")).show(false);
```

Output -

```
|data[2017-07-01].startTime|data[2017-07-01].endTime|
+------------------------------------+--------------+
|1498854000                |1498870800              |
```

This is the result after collecting the reuslts for -

```
MyClass userData = results.collectAsList().get(0); MyDTO userDTO = userData.getData().get("2017-07-01"); System.out.println("userDTO startTime: " + userDTO.getStartTime()); System.out.println("userDTO endTime: " + userDTO.getEndTime());
```

--

```
data startTime: 1498870800
data endTime: 1498854000
```

Any clue? is it a spark issue? How can I bypass it?

Comment: I have seen similar problems. Any workaround or known bug ?

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere  when you go from 'spark' to 'java'

Comment: The work around that I found is df.toJSON() and then using jackson object mapper to cast to the desired class.
This is a major issue specially when the data members are from different type, see my bug here - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21402

Answer (score 2):

You can add setters and getters with column index for work around this bug [SPARK-21402](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21402).

```
public static class MyDTO {
    private long startTime;
    private long endTime;

    public long get1StartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void set1StartTime(long startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public long get2EndTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void set2EndTime(long endTime) {
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }
}
```